# how to split string using shell scripting and regex

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a string that is of the form (but not this particular length):

<first part>-<second part>

I have tried:

```
 read var1 var2 <<< $(sed -r 's/\-/& /' <<< $STRING)
```

This gets me:

```
 var1 = "<first part>-"
 var2 = "<second part>"
```

How can I get it such that

```
 var1 = "<first part>"
 var2 = "<second part>"
```

I don't necessarily need to use sed, it just seemed like the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
IFS="-" read -r var1 var2 <<< "$string"
```

---

> `IFS`: Internal Field Separator